# Ruby Gem - Can't Convert String Into Integer Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-product-api

I am using the [a2z gem](https://github.com/mhuggins/a2z) to work with Amazon's Product Advertising API and I'm running into this issue with the gem when I try to specify multiple product_ids into an item_lookup request.  Is this something I can fix, or do I have to contact the gem author?

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Here is my code:

```
def product_lookup
    # Check which Retailer this is for
    case params[:retailer] 
        when "amazon"
            client = A2z::Client.new(key: ENV["AMAZON_PAAPI_KEY"], secret: ENV["AMAZON_PAAPI_SECRET"], tag: ENV["AMAZON_PAAPI_TAG"])
            product_ids = []
            product_ids << product_one_id = params[:product_one_id]
            product_ids << product_two_id = "B00D43QGPS"
            product_ids = product_ids.join(",")

            @products = client.item_lookup do
                 id product_ids
                 response_group 'Small, Images, OfferListings'
            end

            render :json => @products

    end
end
```

Comment: The great part about GitHub is that you *can* fix anything. :) You can fork, fix, and submit a pull request, then point your app at your fork of a2z until the author has time to merge. Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Given the definition of `id` at https://github.com/mhuggins/a2z/blob/master/lib/a2z/requests/item_lookup.rb, it's clear that it expects the format you're passing in the sense of comma separated values, so the problem must be deeper. Note also that you can omit doing the `join` yourself as the `id` method will do it for you if passed an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Gem creator here. :)  Thanks for the question and for adding the issue on Github.

I'm wondering if something changed either in a gem dependency or in the Amazon response structure, unless I just inadvertently broke it through another change since the gem is lacking tests at the moment.

I see what the problem is: the response is an array of hashes (i.e.: multiple products), and I'm just treating it as a hash (i.e.: a single product).  I'll need to change the response parsing to account for arrays, which shouldn't be too hard.  Let me see if I can get a fix together.